# FB.ui is not Defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, share, fb.ui

Using BugSnag, I can see that some of our users on our website are runnning into this error:

```
FB.ui is not a function
```

When I visit the site and get to the page that this error is appearing, I have no issues.
Here is our script to share to fb:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=1365705806909063&autoLogAppEvents=1';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="x-custom-col" id="share-fb-btn">
    <a class="x-fb x-btn" data-social-type="fb-share" data-eventlabel="inlineshare">
        <i class="ico-facebook"></i>
        <span>Share to Facebook!</span>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('share-fb-btn').onclick = function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: {
                    'og:url':"http://www.example.com/",
                    'og:title': "Here is some info to share!".",
                    'og:description': "Decribe it!",
                    'og:image': "https://www.example.com/image"
                }
            })
        },
        function (response) {
            // Action after response
        });
    }
</script>
```

It seems this is only happening on our mobile layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: The SDK is loaded asynchronously, so it might simply not have loaded/initialized already, when users click your button. Either assign the click handler from inside the init event handler of the SDK, or _check_ whether the FB object exists before you try to call its method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if someone uses a tool to block external scripts for social media and analytics. It blocks loading the script, so FB will not get initialized and FB.ui will not exist.

You can solve this by checking if FB exists, or by adding the click listener in the `window.fbAsyncInit` callback of the JavaScript SDK.